# May I rescale Google ads from AdMob/DFP?

Tags: android, google-dfp, admob, double-click-advertising

I have implement ads in new application. There is a tile grid layout where I would like put ads between content items. The tile has different sizes on different devices. Its size is calculated in percentage.

I want to set ad the same width and height as regular content items. 
I have one solution:

```
    int width = getConentTileWidth();
    int height = getContentTileHeight();
    AdSize customAdSize = new AdSize(width, height);
    publisherAdView.setAdSizes(customAdSize);
```

This is looks fine, but I don't know if ad team have to handle it somehow. In old app there was used this type AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGL and it was rescaled to fit on each device. There are any difference for ad system? Ad team have to buy/request new size of ads if I use custom size?

is it possible to get ad in this way and rescale it:

```
 publisherAdView.setAdSizes(AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE);
```

and on onAdLoaded callback get the publisherAdView (or get child) and force set width, height. I don't know if not allowed by Google.
Some one can confirm it?

There is other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend trying to scale AdMob banners or DFP banners that target AdX backfill. They're designed and formatted to fit certain sizes.

The Native Express format, on the other hand, is built to handle a wide range of sizes, which you can set on the fly when making requests. I'd recommend having a look at the [guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-express) and [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZY4EJ34Jb7o&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKX0pUJV3uqp6N3NeHwHh0c&index=7) if you haven't already.